# Load html, js and css widget into external site via ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a web page that should fire an ajax request to load into a div a widget consisting of a html block, a css file and 2 js files (jquery lib and file that holds the widget logics).

What is the best way to get the external code into the main site and what to do in order to not interfere with other .js libraries and .css classes that are loaded in the main site?

Currently I am using iframes but because of several reasons I want to remove them.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

The long and the short? You can't access 3rd party content programmatically from your page. You can create 'pages in pages'(iframes) so to speak.

Or you can make the 3rd party content part of your page using html tags like `<script>` and `<style>`. This would mean, though, that the content would possibily interface with yours.

If you have access to the 3rd party server, you can use CORS.

But due to many cross-site-scripting security concerns, cross-site coding is prohibited

Comment: one does not load css with ajax, only html, json, xml, etc.

Comment: People use ajax for anything and with the introduction of XHR2.0, ajax can be used to retrieve anythong from simple text, to imgs, videos, etc: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/ But with that said, I was more targeting the request that OP didn't want the widget to interact/face with his page.

Comment: Both, the main site and the widget could be under the same domain to avoid cross domain policy problems.